# Javascript create cookie every hour, if cookie not exists, and if cookie exists : do redirect to other url

Tags: javascript, redirect, cookies, settimeout

I'm trying to make a function that create cookie every on hour, (and the function will check if this cookie not exists, every hour), and if the cookie exists, the function will do redirect to other page with settimeout()every one mintue.
I'm attached the code I did, but it's not working as expected, because I don't know how make the first part :

```
<script>
function redirect(){
/**create cookie every hour, check if cookie exists, if not create and redirect the page every one mintue***/
      document.cookie = 'createCookie=ok';
      let createCookie = document.cookie;     
/**create cookie every hour, check if cookie exists, if not create and redirect the page every one mintue***/
      
    setTimeout(function(){  
        if(createCookie != null){
            //if cookie set
            window.location.href='https://www.google.com/';
        }
        else{
            //if cookie not set
        }

    }, 60000);

redirect();//to recall the script after it is done
}
</script>
```

Comment: The description and the comments are contradicting. In the description: _"if the cookie exists, the function will do redirect to other page"_, in the comments: _"if not create and redirect the page"_

Answer (score 0):

However it is not a recommended approach as you are not cleaning the interval anywhere, but here you go:

```js
function redirect() {
  document.cookie = 'createCookie=ok';
  let createCookie = document.cookie;

  setInterval(function() {
    if (createCookie != null) {
      //if cookie set
      window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/';
    } else {
      document.cookie = 'createCookie=ok';
      let createCookie = document.cookie;
    }

  }, 60000);

}

redirect()
```

Comment: Thanks! it's good direction, however - how can I make the cookie set and check happens every HOUR ? not a minute (60000) ?

Comment: Exchange `60000` with `3600000`